# Has no attribute getitem

Tags: python

I'm trying to integrate Pagseguro (a brazilian payment service, similar to PayPal) with this lib

https://github.com/rochacbruno/python-pagseguro

But, I don't know how to access the data from notification that the service sends to me. This is my code:

```
notification_code = request.POST['notificationCode']
pg = PagSeguro(email="testPerson@gmail.com", token="token")
notification_data = pg.check_notification(notification_code)
print notification_data['status']
```

In the las line I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PagSeguroNotificationResponse' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation in the README doesn't seem to match the code.  It looks like rather than `notication_data` being a dictionary it is an object that has attributes matching the dictionary keys from the README.

So this should work if you just change `print notification_data['status']` to the following:

```
print notification_data.status
```